# why is this C++ program using constructor and destructor showing error?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

The following program is showing error:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
int count = 0;
class alpha
   {
   public:

   alpha()
         {
         count++;
         cout<<"\n Number of objects created "<<count; 
         }
  ~alpha()
         {
         cout<<"\n Number of object destroyed"<<count;
         count--;
         }
  };

int main
{
    cout<<" inside main ";
    alpha a1, a2, a3, a4;
    {
        cout<<"\n Block 1 ";
        alpha A5;
    }
    {
        cout<<"\n Block 2 ";
        alpha a6;
    }
    cout<<" main again ";
    return 0;
}
```

> Line 11: error: reference to 'count' is ambiguous compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: This shouldn't compile at all, there is no such header `iostream.h` and you're not `using namespace std;` but you're using `cout` etc. Also you're missing the `()` after `main`.

Comment: looks like C code with a class in it.. don't use globals if possible.. a static class member has the same effect as your count variable.

Comment: Could you at least tell us what is the line 11? Counting the lines shows the line 11 in your published source only contains the destructor's prototype line (i.e. `~alpha()`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no header `<iostream.h>` in standard C++. Use the header `<iostream>` which has names in `std` namespace, thus not polluting the global namespace with names as `count`. 
Don't forget to use `std::cin`, `std::cout` etc. from now on.

If your compiler doesn't recognize `<iostream>`, throw it away and get a new one. [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express), for one, is free and easy to use, though not extremely standards-compliant at the moment, but that should not be a big issue for you.

Comment: And you can find alternatives on that [C++ tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info).

Answer (score 5):

You have several problems with your code:

1. You don't need `conio.h`
2. There is no such header as `iostream.h`, it's just `iostream`
3. You're missing the `()` after the word `main`
4. You're using `cout`, `endl` etc when they're not in the namespace you're working in.

After fixing all the errors, you get something like this:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int count = 0;

class alpha
   {
public:
alpha()
       {
       count++;
       cout<<"\n Number of objects created "<<count; 
       }
~alpha()
       {
       cout<<"\n Number of object destroyed"<<count;
       count--;
       }
};

int main()
    {
    cout<<" inside main ";
    alpha a1, a2, a3, a4;
        {
        cout<<"\n Block 1 ";
        alpha A5;
        }
        {
        cout<<"\n Block 2 ";
        alpha a6;
        }
    cout<<" main again ";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of your count variable slightly.  I think "count" might have special meaning in a stream.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem; it would be resolved via namespacing.